Retrieving extended properties from Google task
I am trying to create a Google task using the Task API, and when doing so, add an extended property or Client data. Then retrieve the property or data when I read the task later.
My json when creating the task looks like this:
{
    "title":    "Test Task to Google",
    "extendedProperties":   {
        "private":  {
            "ABCCoCreated": "yes"
        }
    },
    "clientData":   [{
            "key":  "isABCCo",
            "value":    "yes"
        }],
    "due":  "2024-05-13T07:00:00-07:00",
    "status":   "needsAction"
}

Google accepts this no problem and creates the task.  The problem is, when reading the task back, using the API:
https://tasks.googleapis.com/tasks/v1/lists/{tasklist}/tasks/{task}

There is no sign of clientData or a private property. I use this technique with contacts and calendar entries and it works, but not for tasks. Any ideas how I can do this, or if it's possible?

When I saw the official document of Resource: Task", I cannot find the properties extendedProperties and clientData. I'm worried that this might be related to your current issue. By the way, about I use this technique with contacts and calendar entries and it works, in the case of event object of Calendar API, extendedProperties is existing. But, I cannot find the property clientData. I apologize for this situation.

It seems that the Google APIs will ignore json elements that it doesn't support, which I guess is reasonable.  It would be good if Google can start supporting extendedProperties in the task resource.
